# Java DataInputStream hung with no errors

Tags: java

I'm writing a client and server app for file transfer. In the download functionality the client seems to be getting hung at a call to the readUTF function call. I've attached the code snippet below. I get no errors or any other warnings. If anyone has any insight I'd be greatly appreciative.

Client:

```
os = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
os.println(fileName);
System.out.println("sending file name to server");

// wait for server to confirm file exists on server
String codeTest = input.readLine();
int code = Integer.parseInt(codeTest);

System.out.println("Code received from server: " + code);

while (code == 0) {
    System.out.println("File: " + fileName + " does not exist on server!");
    System.out.print("Please enter the file name you would like to download: ");
    fileName = sc.next();
    os.println(fileName);
    codeTest = input.readLine();
    code = Integer.parseInt(codeTest);
}

if (code == 1) {

    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dataInStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    // download
    System.out.println("File exists on the server!");

    String fileToSave = "";

    // get OS downloads directory
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name");

    if ( operatingSystem.startsWith("Windows") ) {
        fileToSave = home + "\\" + "Downloads\\";
    } else {
        System.out.println(home);
        fileToSave = home + "/" + "Downloads/";
    }

    System.out.println(fileToSave + fileName);

    fileToSave += fileName;
    System.out.println("file to download: " + fileToSave);
    int bytesRead;

    System.out.println("got streams");

    fileName = dataInStream.readUTF();
    System.out.println("fileName from server: " + fileName);
    fileToSave += fileName;
    System.out.println("File to save: " + fileToSave);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream((fileToSave));
    long size = dataInStream.readLong();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = dataInStream.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        size -= bytesRead;
    }
    System.out.println("file downloaded successfully");

    continue;
}
```

Server

```
System.out.println("user selected upload");

DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

//String fileName = input.readLine();
String fileName = clientData.readUTF();

if ( fileName.equals("q")) {
    System.out.println("continue");
    continue;
}

//System.out.println("fileName received: " + fileName);
String fileNameToStore = DIRECTORY + fileName;

System.out.println("Saving file to: " + fileNameToStore);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileNameToStore);

int bytesRead;
long size = clientData.readLong();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

while( size>0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    size -= bytesRead;
}

output.close();
//clientData.close();

System.out.println("done");

break;
case "d":
System.out.println("user selected download");

//handle file download

String requestedFile = input.readLine();
String fileToDownload = DIRECTORY + requestedFile;

System.out.println("User requested: " + fileToDownload);

// check if file exists and tell client 
File file = new File(fileToDownload);

int code;
while ( !file.exists() ) {
    code = 0;

    textOut.println(code);

    System.out.println("Code sent to client: " + code);

    // wait for file name
    requestedFile = input.readLine();
    System.out.println("user resent filename: " + fileToDownload);

    file = new File(fileToDownload);
} 

// file exists - send to client
code = 1;
textOut.println(code);

byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
System.out.println("dos writeUTF: " + file.getName());
dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
System.out.println(mybytearray.length + " sent to client.");
dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
dos.flush();
System.out.println("File "+fileToDownload+" sent to client.");


break;
```

Comment: Maybe there is no data to read?

Comment: I thought that, but the server side says that it sent the file...  I should've included the server side code

Comment: read couple of bytes then to see if something is there. besides maybe server didnt flush the buffer?

Comment: @Antoniossss I edited and added the server portion...

Comment: whats input on client side?

Comment: It's a BufferedReader that I use to read in a code from server signifying whether or not the file exists on the server.

Really appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: Try to read couple of bytes using inpustream in the same place where dis hangs. Is it hanging too?

Comment: Moreover you dont read your file into mybytearray so you kind of sending filesize number of zeros

Comment: Yes it is. I added a test variable

//fileName = dataInStream.readUTF();
int test = inputStream.read();
System.out.println("test: " + test);

Still hung

Comment: Hi! It's awesome you found a solution and want to share it with us :) However I just reverted your edit, because solutions are not supposed to be in the question. Instead post an answer. It's highly encouraged to answer your own questions if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working. I simply added an output from client to server letting the server know that the client was ready for the file to be sent. I did this right before the fileName = dataInStream.readUTF();

I'm not sure why that fixed it, but it did. Thanks for the help.